# Projects to practice class inheritance and OOP

Tags: oop, inheritance, project

I am wondering if there are any good small/medium sized programs that I or others could make that would be good for practicing OOP or using inheritance in. I haven't seen any questions asked like this, so I figure it would be a good question for others to use in the future as well.

A project I have done already:

**Inventory Manager:** Controls the inventory of a shop and assigns the item type, price, etc. All of which you use inheritance to sort out products

The problem with this is that it can only go so far into the practice.

Any other ideas for projects that you have used to further your knowledge of the subject?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure InventoryManger is proper OOP? Change it. Add new products, change existing inventory rules etc and see how easy it is to implement changes. Anyone can write applications that do something, that doesn't mean they're reliable or maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple photo editor that lets you apply filters such as blur, sharpen or emboss can make a good example of using the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). It's interesting to find the best way to implement the undo/redo feature. The [memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) may come in handy!

When designing the application structure keep in mind that later you will want to add new filters/effects. Then try adding them! If you're saving the image to a jpg, try adding a "save to png" feature. What if later you decide to support another format? Is your application easily extensible? Leave it be for a couple weeks and come back to it later. Can you still easily add a new effect or a new export format? Try it out!

Answer (score 2):

A automobile dealership or rental car agency makes a good OO modeling problem. As far as inheritance, there are different kinds of vehicles and different kinds of contracts (sale, lease, loaner).